# Returning objects created by chained javascript promises

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, angular, promise, ionic2

I am struggling to wrap my head around chaining together promises to achieve a desired result.

Brief background: 
I'm Using Ionic2 (based on Angular2) to create mobile app. Data persistence is based on SQLite. In order to re-build a complex object that contains nested arrays, I need to chain together a number of database calls.

```
buildObjectFromID(id) {

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        let db = new DBHelper();

        try {

          // Get the event object from id
          db.getEventWithCMSID(id).then(event => {

            db.getBannerForOwner(event.cmsId).then(banner => {
              event.banner = banner;
            });
            db.getImagesForOwner(event.cmsId).then(images => {
              event.images = images;
            });

            db.getProfilePicturesForOwner(event.cmsId).then(profilepictures => {
              event.profilepicture = profilepictures;
            });

            db.getLogosForOwner(event.cmsId).then(logos => {
              event.logos = logos;
            });

            resolve(event);

          });
        }
        catch
          (err) {
          reject({err: err});
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

This method aims to fetch a main object from the database, and using it's ID, fetches and appends its related properties from additional tables. I wish to rebuild the object in it's entirety before passing the result back.

However, at the moment, the object is passed back and then over time the properties are added once each additional call is completed.

I would really appreciate if someone could inform me how I can chain these together, so that the controller calling 'buildObjectFromID' gets a complete object.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two changes you can make:

1. Remember that `then` returns a new promise. Since you already have a promise from `db.getEventWithCMSID`, you don't need to use `new Promise` at all, just use the one you get from calling `then` on that one. In general, before reaching for `new Promise`, consider whether you already have one the work with.
2. To wait for all of your subordinate operations to complete, use `Promise.all`.

So:

```
buildObjectFromID(id) {
    let db = new DBHelper();

    return db.getEventWithCMSID(id).then(event => {
        return Promise.all([
            db.getBannerForOwner(event.cmsId).then(banner => {
              event.banner = banner;
            }),
            db.getImagesForOwner(event.cmsId).then(images => {
              event.images = images;
            }),
            db.getProfilePicturesForOwner(event.cmsId).then(profilepictures => {
              event.profilepicture = profilepictures;
            }),
            db.getLogosForOwner(event.cmsId).then(logos => {
              event.logos = logos;
            })
        ]).then(() => {
            return event;
        });
    });
}
```

[**Live Example** on Babel's REPL](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015&code=class%20DBHelper%20%7B%0A%20%20getEventWithCMSID(id)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20new%20Promise(resolve%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20setTimeout(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20resolve(%7BcmsId%3A%20id%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%200)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20getBannerForOwner(id)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20new%20Promise(resolve%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20resolve(%22banner%20%22%20%2B%20id)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%200)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20getImagesForOwner(id)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20new%20Promise(resolve%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20resolve(%22images%20%22%20%2B%20id)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%200)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0Afunction%20buildObjectFromID(id)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20db%20%3D%20new%20DBHelper()%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20return%20db.getEventWithCMSID(id).then(event%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20Promise.all(%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20db.getBannerForOwner(event.cmsId).then(banner%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20event.banner%20%3D%20banner%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20db.getImagesForOwner(event.cmsId).then(images%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20event.images%20%3D%20images%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D).then(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20event%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%7D%0AbuildObjectFromID(42)%0A%20%20.then(event%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(event)%3B%0A%20%20%7D)%0A%20%20.catch(e%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.error(e)%3B%0A%20%20%7D)%3B) *(for brevity I left out two of the subordinate calls, just include banner and images)*

That also has the advantage of propagating failures, which your original code didn't do (consider what happens if `getBannerForOwner` fails, for instance).

[**Live Example** on Babel's REPL demonstrating failure](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015&code=class%20DBHelper%20%7B%0A%20%20getEventWithCMSID(id)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20new%20Promise(resolve%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20setTimeout(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20resolve(%7BcmsId%3A%20id%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%200)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20getBannerForOwner(id)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20new%20Promise((resolve%2C%20reject)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20reject(%22failed%20to%20get%20banner%20for%20%22%20%2B%20id)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%200)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20getImagesForOwner(id)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20new%20Promise(resolve%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20resolve(%22images%20%22%20%2B%20id)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%200)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0Afunction%20buildObjectFromID(id)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20db%20%3D%20new%20DBHelper()%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20return%20db.getEventWithCMSID(id).then(event%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20Promise.all(%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20db.getBannerForOwner(event.cmsId).then(banner%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20event.banner%20%3D%20banner%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20db.getImagesForOwner(event.cmsId).then(images%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20event.images%20%3D%20images%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D).then(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20event%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%7D%0AbuildObjectFromID(42)%0A%20%20.then(event%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(%22success%22%2C%20event)%3B%0A%20%20%7D)%0A%20%20.catch(e%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.error(%22error%22%2C%20e)%3B%0A%20%20%7D)%3B)

Comment: Thank you so much for your fast response T.J.

Comment: Your solution is very in depth. I appreciate it very much. This solves my issue on building the object in the correct order and returning the full object, however, the calling method of buildObjectFromID is also a Promise, of which I am still having issues. Should I raise another question, or update my original?

Comment: @PhillipHartin: Glad that helps. Since that's pretty new information and there are already two answers on the question, I'd say your instinct to open a new question instead is probably best.

Answer (score 1):

I would leverage the `Promise.all` method and chain different promises like this:

```
buildObjectFromID(id) {
  let db = new DBHelper();

  // Get the event object from id
  return db.getEventWithCMSID(id).then(event => {
    return Promise.all([
      event,
      db.getBannerForOwner(event.cmsId),
      db.getImagesForOwner(event.cmsId),
      db.getProfilePicturesForOwner(event.cmsId),
      db.getLogosForOwner(event.cmsId)
    ]);
  }).then(result => {
    let event = result[0];
    let banner = result[1];
    let images = result[2];
    let logos = result[3];

    event.banner = banner;
    event.images = images;
    event.profilepicture = profilepictures;
    event.logos = logos;
    return event;
  });
}
```