# Correct use of then in javascript promises

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, promise, ionic2

I am having some issues correctly handling the responses of various promises.

Brief background: I'm Using Ionic2 (based on Angular2) to create mobile app. Data persistence is based on SQLite. In order to re-build a complex object that contains nested arrays, I need to chain together a number of database calls.

In the method below, I am fetching a list of ScheduledEvents. For each event, I then fetch its associated objects (shown in buildObjectFromID) -> This method works well thanks to [Returning objects created by chained javascript promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37072571/returning-objects-created-by-chained-javascript-promises)

When this object is returned, however, I wish for the method getSchedule(), to return the updated list only once all the elements have been processed in the forEach section. At the moment, it seems the scheduledEvents object is returned immediately, and actually updates over time, as the method continues to execute.

**schedule-controller.js**

```
 getSchedule() {

    let db = new DBHelper();
    let scheduleController = new ScheduleController();

    return db.getScheduledEvents().then(scheduledEvents => {
      //  For each scheduled event, get the related object
      scheduledEvents.forEach(scheduledEvent => {
        scheduleController.buildObjectFromId(scheduledEvent.id).then(relatedObject => {
          //update object with new property 
          scheduledEvent.data = relatedObject;
        });
      }).then(() => {
        //Once all properties have been updated, return updated array
        return scheduledEvents;
      });
    });
  }


buildObjectFromID(id) {

    let db = new DBHelper();
    return db.getSpeakerWithCMSID(id).then(speaker => {
      return Promise.all([
        db.getBannerForOwner(speaker.cmsId).then(banner => {
          speaker.banner = banner;
        }),
        db.getImagesForOwner(speaker.cmsId).then(images => {
          speaker.images = images;
        }),
        db.getProfilePicturesForOwner(speaker.cmsId).then(profilepictures => {
          speaker.profilepicture = profilepictures;
        })
      ]).then(() => {
        return speaker;
      });
    });
```

I would greatly appreciate any help or direction with this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've forgotten to return the result of `scheduledEvents.forEach().then()` Without that the promise returned by `getSchedule()` will resolve immediately to `undefined`

(I assume `scheduledEvents.forEach` is some abstraction of `Array.forEach` that returns a Promise once the iteration is done, and not `Array.forEach` itself, otherwise its result wouldn't even have a `then` method.)

```
return db.getScheduledEvents().then(scheduledEvents => {
  //  For each scheduled event, get the related object
  return scheduledEvents.forEach(scheduledEvent => {
    scheduleController.buildObjectFromId(scheduledEvent.id).then(relatedObject => {
      //update object with new property 
      scheduledEvent.data = relatedObject;
    });
  }).then(() => {
    //Once all properties have been updated, return updated array
    return scheduledEvents;
  });
});
```

(Also you can replace `() => { return foo; }` with `() => foo`)

---

Actually I see no way that `scheduledEvents.forEach` can be anything special and still work. Even if it was an abstraction that returned a Promise, you seem to be doing async work inside the lambda without returning those promises either. So I'm beginning to think it's just regular Array.forEach and you've made a mistake there as well.

In that case what you want is `Array.map` to create an array of promises of the work you want to perform on the individual scheduledEvents, then wait on them all with `Promise.all`

```
return db.getScheduledEvents().then(scheduledEvents => {
  //  For each scheduled event, get the related object
  return Promise.all(scheduledEvents.map(scheduledEvent => {
    return scheduleController.buildObjectFromId(scheduledEvent.id).then(relatedObject => {
      //update object with new property 
      scheduledEvent.data = relatedObject;
    });
  })).then(() => {
    //Once all properties have been updated, return updated array
    return scheduledEvents;
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much with your help. It seems to work perfectly. I understand now the issue that I was having. 13 hrs of straight coding and my brain couldn't handle any more async work! Thank you again. You have made my weekend!